# Am I using the compareTo method properly

Tags: java

I am stuck on the following question:

> Study the following Java class header and code fragment:
>
> ```
> class ExamScript implements Comparable<ExamScript>
> {
>     private String studentName;
>     private int mark;
>     ...rest of class...
>
>     /**
>       * Compares this object with the specified object for e
>       *@param e the object to be compared
>       *@return -1 if object is less than the specified object
>       *@return 0 if object is equal to the specfied object
>      **/
>        public int compareTo(ExamScript e)
>        {
>          if (mark < e.mark)
>              return - 1;
>          if (mark == e.mark)
>              return 0;
>          return 1;
>        }
> }
> ```
>
> Give suitable documentation for the `compareTo` method. In particular state the meaning of the values returned from this method.
>
> Write the code for the `compareTo` method according to your specification.

I've documented and written the code as shown above. Can anyone confirm for me if I can improve my documentation/coding a bit or if that is fine the way it is?

Comment: What happens when you test this code? Does the program behave as you'd want it to behave?

Comment: belongs on the 'code review' site.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add `@returns 1 if e is greater than this object.`

You can be more specific with your @returns.  Try using the format I used above.  Also, if it's not apparent from reading the code, try to explain what mark is, and why it's being used to compare.

Check [Oracle's standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-142372.html#method) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

the problem I see it that when the grades are equal the student are considered equal (at least when algorithms assume `a.compareTo(b)==0` implies `a.equals(b)` depending on your use this might be a good thing

but if it's bad you can fix this by comparing the names instead of returning 0

```
public int compareTo(ExamScript e)
{
  if (mark < e.mark)
      return - 1;
  if (mark == e.mark)
      return studentName.compareTo(e.studentName);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: And this is why one shouldn't use compareTo in place of equals. By definition, compareTo returns relative rank as based on natural ordering and has nothing to do with equals. Programs that assume that the two are related are using the method in a way in which it wasn't intended -- unless the docs for the class implementing this method specifically states otherwise. I think that this is a non-issue.